# Java how to create new HashMap and remove from it

Tags: java, hashmap

I have HashMap and want to save original HashMap information into another variable. After this I have to delete one record from new created variable/HashMap. My `public` is repeating few times, so I want to have original `address` HashMap information. I done it by this way, but this code also removes record from original `address` HashMap, not only from new `th`. What's wrong here? How to remove record only from `th`, but keep all information in `address`?

```
public static final Home newInstance( //
        DbHome homeplan, //
        Map<String, BigDecimal> address) {
    
    Map<String, BigDecimal> th;
    th = address;

    th.remove("NED");
```

Comment: You need to create a copy just like Prophet showed in their answer. Note that this is true for basically any object you pass to a method: if you need to keep the original state you need to create a copy of that parameter first. Java won't create copies of objects you pass as parameters for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new `HashMap` object and initialize it with values of existing `HashMap` `address`, not just create additional pointer to the existing `address` object.

```
public static final Home newInstance( //
        DbHome homeplan, //
        Map<String, BigDecimal> address) {
    
    Map<String, BigDecimal> th;
    th = new HashMap<>(address);

    th.remove("NED");
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to copying the map and removing is to filter the map's entries using streams:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> th =
    address.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals("NED"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

(Copying the map and removing is probably nicer).